# Issue in protecting a folder in wwwroot folder of ASP .Net Core project

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

I'm trying to protect a folder in **wwwroot** folder of my .Net Core project with the following code inside **startup.cs**:

```
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Users"))
            {
                if (context.User.Identities.Any(identity => identity.IsAuthenticated))
                {
                    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Users") && context.Request.Path.Value.LastIndexOf("/") > 0)
                    {
                        var clientID = Guid.Parse(context.Request.Path.Value.Split("/"[0])[2]);
                        if (context.GetClientID() != clientID && !context.User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                            await context.Authentication.ForbidAsync();
                        else
                            await next();
                    }
                    else
                        await next();
                }
                else
                    await context.Authentication.ChallengeAsync();
            }
            else
                await next();
        });
```

Everything works fine in Visual Studio and IIS Express but when I publish the project to production in IIS, **context.User.Identities.Any(identity => identity.IsAuthenticated)** always returns **false**. Even when I use **context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated** it returns false.

But this redirects user to the login page although they're logged in and when user logs is again, it works.

This is the code for my cookie authentication:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = CoreApplicationInfo.AuthenticationScheme,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
            CookieName = CoreApplicationInfo.ApplicationCookie,
            CookieHttpOnly = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true
        });
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

Create www folder and locate a file.

Next :(Specify the path with own code)

```
[Authorize] 
public IActionResult File() 
{
  return PhysicalFile(Path.Combine(environment.ContentRootPath, "www", "banner1.svg"), "image/svg+xml");
}
```

Best regards.

https://medium.com/@tanaka_733/static-file-authorization-in-asp-net-core-mvc-26c1069073c1